# Generic Function with Special Case for String

Tags: .net, vb.net

What's the best way to handle this situation:

I have this generic function

```
Function FieldValue(Of T)(row As DataRow,fieldName As String) As T
  Return If(row.IsNull(fieldName),Nothing,CType(row(fieldName),T))
End Function
```

in the special case where the field value is null and T is String, I want to return String.Empty instead of Nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to provide a specific function for T = string:

```
Function FieldValue(row As DataRow ,fieldName As String) As String
  Return If(row.IsNull(fieldName), String.Empty, CType(row(fieldName), String))
End Function
```

(on top of your existing generic function)

---

Here's another option:

```
Function FieldValue(Of T)(row As DataRow,fieldName As String) As T
    If GetType(T) = GetType(String) And row.IsNull(fieldName) Then
        Return CType(CType(String.Empty, Object), T)
    Else
        Return If(row.IsNull(fieldName), Nothing, CType(row(fieldName), T))
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I'd like to be able to continue to call the function the same way I have been, i.e. `Dim fv As String = FieldValue(of String)(row,fieldName)`

Comment: I had tried returning `New T` instead of `Nothing`, but that results in `'New' cannot be used on a type parameter that does not have a 'New' constraint.`

Comment: I added another way to do it within the same generic function. You would need a type constraint to be able to use New, but you would limit the use of the function to types that have an anonymous constructor.

Comment: Your answer is brilliant!  Cheers!

Comment: Why not just call the Field extension method in conjunction with the If operator?   Dim s As String = If(dataRow.Field(Of String)("ColumnName"), String.Empty)